# How to ensure that players don't forget they're always in a microgravity environment

Tags: eclipse-phase, science-fiction

In Eclipse Phase, the default assumption is that there is virtually no gravity.
Indeed this is the default assumption in most hard(-ish) space scifi.

There are 3 places in Eclipse Phase that have Earth-like gravity:

- Spinning Space Stations: you are on the inside of a cylinder, pushed to the edge by Centrifugal force
- Planets and Large Moons
- Simuspace (i.e. Virtual Reality)

Places lots of people live have gravity, especially if they're conservatives in the inner sphere.
Ships aren't normally worth spinning for gravity as there are normally no conscious people involved. If peoples' bodies are being transported, then either their Egos (minds) are in VR, or more likely, those people have ego cast ahead and are renting a body til their preferred morph (body) arrives.

But players spend a lot of time in other places that don't have gravity - at least not to an Earth-like extent:

- Scum barges
- Most smaller/older/cheaper space stations
- Ships
- Asteroids/moons

How can I make sure that I and my players remember that unless explicitly stated otherwise, there is practically no gravity?

We've been playing for 3 or 4 sessions now, and my players *and I* regularly forget that there is no gravity and to describe situations accordingly. This would make sure we imagine things correctly, and take into account the mechanical/practical implications.

Answer (score 11):

Decribe the situation accordingly, using proper terms.

Instead of saying "you are there" say **"you are floating there"**. This should be a pretty strong reminder.

Plus, force them to use the near-0 gravity, for instance placing objects in locations they couldn't reach with Earth-like gravity.

---

However I'm puzzled: which problem *exactly* did you encounter with that? Reading your question I have the feeling you didn't start playing, and you assume there will be problems. If yes, I suggest you come back once you have *specific* problems, if not, then you should really explain what *exactly* didn't work.

Answer (score 11):

Put a tented index card labeled **No Gravity** in the middle of the table.

Answer (score 4):

Place a small flashlight or a small led (red) light on the table. Turn it on (taking care not to shine it in anyone's eyes, obviously :)) to indicate "no gravity". Turn it off when things are normal. Do tell your players the meaning of it all beforehand, though. :)

(Sure, you can use any other prop that stands out as well. Or, you know, music: a track that plays when there's no gravity. Or a sound, if you're already using music (to enhance the mood of your story), that works besides music, and which indicates the environment the PCs are in. ([Example.](http://mynoise.net/NoiseMachines/fanNoiseGenerator.php))

Answer (score 4):

## Use Indirect Reminders

### For Yourself

Obviously we can't advise you to 'just remember things better' - you can't simply will yourself directly do that. But as a GM, surely you have some procedures that you go through when setting up a scene. Some sort of mental checklist that you go through, such as deciding what things are present in the scene.

One of the common things about scenes is that they can be described as happening in some sort of room - be it a room of a building, station, or just the interior of a vehicle of some sort. And they have walls. What are the walls like *and why*? Try to get used to thinking about that question, as it's quite a useful one in all cases of setting up a scene, and should serve as a memory pump for recalling about low gravity/freefall. Rooms intended for freefall operation are likely to have handholds, and lack clearly differentiated floors and ceilings (or at least have 'multifunctional' floors if they're meant to be exposed to real gravity periodically).

Hopefully while going through the mental checklist, you'll remember whether to turn the '[freefall light](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37534/how-to-ensure-that-players-dont-forget-theyre-always-in-a-microgravity-environ/37552#37552)' on or off. And once you have a mental picture of the scene, the little things (see below) will help prevent the gravity situation from slipping out of your mind.

### For the Players

Never just tell your players that their PCs are in freefall over and over again, be indirect here too. Subtly, casually bring attention to the little bits of the scene that are influenced by the lack of gravity:

- Handles on the walls.
- Magnets or gecko pads on boots and items.
- Bouncers with their hand-feet.
- Characters being out of alignment when talking to each other face to face.
- Drinks being in squishable packs instead of glasses.
- Lost items hanging out by the ventilation intake (whether because taken there by air, or *traditionally left there* with the former).
- Dust and sand taking hours to settle (asteroidal microgravity).

Yes, for a veteran spacer, all those things are taken for granted and not worth an extra description (in fact, to a second-generation spacer such a description would probably look similar to how [this](http://www.bzpower.com/board/blog/326/entry-58514-if-all-stories-were-written-like-science-fiction-stories/) looks to us). But for your players, such details should serve as odd and memorable indicators of the environmental differences.